# Breaking an Omer restriction

Tags: minhag, halacha-theory, mourning-aveilus, music, sefirat-ha-omer

In a hypothetical case, I have chosen to observe the restrictions of the Omer during the "first [half](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7068/splitting-sefira-mourning-practices-according-to-rav-moshe-feinstein)."

But then, I am placed in a situation at which [happy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2152/1362) live music is being played. Does my presence there "stop" my Omer and force me to shift to the "second half"? Is "breaking the Omer" an all-or-nothing or can I continue after the breaking?

Comment: I seem to recall hearing that one could go to a Simchah of someone keeping the 'other' half of Sefirah, as long as the person mking the Simchah is following a legitimate Halachic option. The implication was that it didn't 'break' the Sefirah that you kept, and you remained keeping your half. However, I don't have a source offhand, which is why this is remaining as a comment.

Comment: I don't understand how the concept of "breaking the omer" or making up for it makes sense. If someone shoves rice down your throat on Passover are you suddenly forced to allow yourself to eat kitniyot and stop eating sheruya to make up for it?

Comment: @ba except for 2 differences -- in my case, there is a fall back option (the second half) and in my case, no one is forcing me; I just didn't anticipate the situation so it happens without my choice.

Comment: rosends On pesach there is also a fall back option: follow the alternate custom to allow Kitniyot. "happens without my choice" "forcing me" seem identical. (cc @ba)

Comment: @DoubleAA can a person switch minhagim vis-a-vis kitniyot automatically? I have heard that the process is much more demanding.

Comment: @rosends I wasn't aware anyone can automatically switch their custom ever on anything other than by traveling to a place with a different custom with no intention of returning. Whether or not you accidentally were forced to eat Kitniyot when your custom is to avoid doing so then or if you accidentally were forced to listen to happy music when your custom is to avoid doing so then, doesn't seem to matter and you still follow your custom. That's ba's point IINM and it seems sound to me.

Comment: @DoubleAA Then I realize that I don't know how and up to when one forms, declares or even has to have the intent to follow one half or the other.

Comment: Frankly I don't either. I'm not sure there is a good classical model for the modern practice I've seen of being sure to pick one possible 'half' each year. Classically communities had traditions and their constituents followed them. Like waiting after meat. I could understand if you follow your community's practice or your parents' or your rabbi's but not changing every time you eat.

Comment: I'm with BA, please define "breaking" in this case - you brought a passive example that means nothing. If you don't count Omer for a day you're "breaking it" but even actively playing music on Omer does not constitute "breaking" as there's no continuity, just like eating on a fast, even if you ate something you continue fasting, as every moment counts.

Comment: @AlBerko so if I hold the first half, but then arbitrarily decide to get a haircut, every day during the first half, I can still claim that I held the first half, just for specific moments? Or does that implicitly mean that I didn't hold the first half and now need to hold the second half.

Comment: I'm not a Posek, I just explain my view - Omer (as a sort of Avelus in general) is kept on a momentary basis - moment by moment, not all-or-nothing (similarly to a marriage). If you failed one moment you comtinue every other moment. You want to switch Minhag - no problem - make Hataras Nedorim and you're done. 2. It's not about halves - it's 33 out of 50 days. 3. If you feel a moral obligation to Leachmir and keep more - be blessed, but don't present it as switching traditions.

Comment: It doesn't look like one needs hataras nedarim https://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5879 is this a different kind of minhag?